# 150cc chinease dirt bike powerloss bad backfire and no idle

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor

I have a 150cc Chinese dirt bike. About a month ago it started to bog a lot. It could only start on choke, so I took apart the carburetor, cleaned it and put it back together. The problem still there. It doesn't need to start on choke anymore. The bog is pretty bad with constant backfire and it will not idle
(like at all).

The bike doesn't sound the same at all. It becomes really hot really fast and shuts down when I let the gas go. When I try to ride its like it has hiccups. Like there's large pockets of air in the engine. I tried playing with the mixture screws on the carb, but it makes no difference literally.

If I slowly turn on the choke it almost goes back to normal, but backfires badly and shuts off. After that the only way to start is to push start with the choke off and it's back to the insane bog and backfire. There's a small smoke leak from the connection of the silencer and the exhaust connection, but I don't think that's the problem.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the air filter? Has it had a service recently?

Comment: I tried to remove the air filter but its been siliconed into the fitting.

Comment: But i dont think the air filter can cause such backfire and overheating

Comment: I think the former owner might have serviced the air filter

Comment: If i cud post a video it cud really show the condition of the bike

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Hey guys, sorry its been awhile i was trying other ways to fix until i gave up. Took it to a shop recently and the repair guy took out the air filter box, replaced the battery and spark plug. I got the bike back running better than ever with so much power but now its started popping when accelrating

Comment: The pops lag the power of the bike like i said before " hiccups"

Comment: The airfilter has been removed and the carb is gettin air directly i guess, theres like an L tube connected to carb.

Comment: This a new carb by the way.

Comment: I have same problem i have tried 5 carbies 3 of witch are new still same problem (all mikunies) i have had this with other pit bikes as well the only fix i,ve had is change brand of carb

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a fueling problem, as in it's not getting enough fuel. This is the reason for the bike getting hot when you do run it (running lean will cause it to run hot). This leads right back to the carburetor.

You can try one of three things (or all three, if it suits you):

1. Try to clean and/or rebuild the carburetor again. I'd say this would most likely fulfill Einstein's theory of insanity (ie: doing the same thing over again expecting different results).
2. Running a heavy concentration of carb cleaner (like SeaFoam or BG44K) through your carb. This *may* clean up the issue. This is a long shot, but worth a try before moving on.
3. Replace the carburetor. This is most likely your best bet, will save you the most time, and be the easiest to accomplish.

More than likely you got a batch of bad fuel or it sat too long or whatever. The carb no longer wants to function correctly, so your best bet is to replace it. It will take care of it quickly without a lot of muss/fuss.

I doubt at this point you could blame the air filter, as it would only help to make the air/fuel richer, though it wouldn't help with running at higher speed.

Comment: Do you think it might be a problem with the engine maybe the timing chain ?

Comment: I cleaned the carb several times i even used seafoam but the problem persists. It had a hard time starting but after cleaning the carb the bike starts but has the hardest time ideling

Comment: Its like the bike has the worst case of the hicups

Comment: Everything you're saying is pointing to a fuel issue to me. You may just find out how much a new carb is for the thing and see if it's worth it to just replace it, but that's going to be up to you.

Comment: There is a fuel filter on the supply line or screen on the fuel shut off valve that may be clogged. Replace the filter or remove the valve from the tank and clean it.

Comment: Good point @Moab

Comment: Ok let me try organise a new carb. Replace the filter and check this valve in the tank. I was worried it might be a problem in the engine. Thank you guys for your response. You guys are awesome. If you have anymore thoughts pls dont hesitate to add a comment.